# Spark UI's output column, never shows anything

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.5

I'm trying to benchmark queries from the [BigDataBenchmark](https://amplab.cs.berkeley.edu/benchmark/). While doing so I'm collecting info from the Spark's Web UI.

I'm saving the results persistently, but, implicitly  by using the `CREATE TABLE results as ...` construct. I can verify that the query result data  is correctly saved to persistent disk in HDFS. However, I can't see any value for the **output** metrics (see column in image) for the jobs/stages, example given hereafter for query: `CREATE TABLE results as SELECT * FROM rankings where pageRank > 1000`
[image: enter image description]

Followup investigation was to see if Spark was unable to count the output as this was a Hive Query. So I reverted to local disk input and saving to local disk for the sake of investigation. I issued the following:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM rankings where pageRank > 1000" ).write.save("file:///somewhere/on/disk")
```

Still the output metric is empty.

Am I misunderstanding what the output means in Spark's case?

Comment: I'm not sure about where you are trying to see your results! Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I've used _results_ and _output_ consistently, but perhaps I've been not really clear about their meaning. With _output_, I mean the metric in the Spark UI, it is shown in the image as a column and is always empty. The _results_ is simply the query's result. Let me know if I misunderstood you

Comment: Are you actually saving the data in a value? It's seems that you are just trying to save it on disk. Thus you'll not get an output.

Comment: And yes, you have misunderstood what output means here. The UI is just for "monitoring" jobs. It's purpose is not to expose results from computed data.

Comment: So the 'output' only registers outcomes of a query if they're sent back to the driver? As in doing a `sqlContext.sql("SELECT ... ... ").collect` ? I just tried, and even then the output column is still empty

Comment: The output won't show anything! You misunderstood it's use.

Comment: I didn't expect query results in that column, I expect it to show the amount of bytes, just like the input column shows the data 'intake' from disk

Comment: Save your query into a value. You'll see the output size then! And in a new instruction you can write.save(...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90162/discussion-between-hbogert-and-eliasah).

Comment: So far I can only conclude that when saving dataframes, the output metric is not updated. If we convert the DataFrame to RDD first, the output is correctly displayed.